# How to match ECDSA fingerprint between open-ssh and dropbear

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, ecdsa, dropbear

Hi I would like to ask how should I match server fingerprint. I use dropbear for entering HDD password before start and than I use open-ssh. The problem is that when I ssh to enter HDD password I receive warning that ECDSA has changed so I need to delete it from known-hosts and than I am able to enter the password but same process needs to be repeated when I connect than using open-ssh. I would need to "copy" server's identity to be used in both cases.

Comment: looks like: https://serverfault.com/a/728688

Comment: or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/134106/333919

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert private keys from /etc/ssh to dropbear format and place them with correct naming to /etc/dropbear-initramfs.